# Clojure: generate all keyboard typeable characters

Tags: clojure

### Context

I want to generate all characters that can be generated by:

- opening note pad
- pressing a single key on the keyboard
- holding shift + pressing a single key on the keyboard

### What I currently have:

```
(concat (range (int \a) (int \z))
  (range (int \A) (int \Z))
  (range (int \0) (int \9)))
```

then manually appending more characters like ~!@#$%^&*()_+{}|:"<>?,./;'[]\

### Question

Is there a more elegant way of doing this?

### Edits

Yes, I'm referring to US Qwerty keyboard.

Comment: You're talking about the standard US QWERTY keyboard, right?

Comment: @Jeremy: Yes, US Qwerty.

Comment: Nitpicking but you're referring to a standard US **layout**, not keyboard.  A standard US QWERTY *keyboard* can definitely be configured so that, say, pressing F12 generates, say, the EURO symbol.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you look at a [US ASCII chart](http://www.asciitable.com/), it seems that all the characters you want are within `(range 33 127)`. So the simplest way to get a sequence of all those characters is to convert that range to characters.

```
(map char (range 33 127))
```

But if you are trying to validate that a string contains only those characters, have a function like:

```
(defn valid-char? [c]
  (let [i (int c)] 
    (and (> i 32) (< i 127))))
```

Then you can use it with `every?` to validate a string:

```
user=> (every? valid-char? "hello world")
true
user=> (every? valid-char? "héllo world")
false
```

Answer (score 1):

Using the following map form will generate the characters you want.

```
(map #(str (char %)) (range 32 127))
```