# Generate character sequence from 'a' to 'z' in clojure

Tags: clojure, character, sequence

I want to generate character sequence from 'a' to 'z'.
In scala, I can generate character sequence very simply:

```
('a' to 'z')
```

But in clojure, I end up with the following code:

```
(->> (range (int \a) (inc (int \z))) (map char))
```

or

```
(map char (range (int \a) (inc (int \z))))
```

It seems to me verbose. Are there any better ways to do it?

Comment: Your method is fine, if you are concerned with verbosity just wrap it in a function: (defn to [start end] (->> (range (int start)) ...)), then (to 'a' 'z') works.

Comment: You could make this *slightly* less verbose by getting rid of the `->>` macro here, because that seems quite unnecessary:`(map char (range (int \a) (int \z)))`.

Comment: Also, I agree with @user593508 here that you could very easily write a function yourself that will do what you want. `(defn char-range [start-char end-char] (map char (range (int start-char) (int end-char))))`. Then `(char-range \a \z)` should work, as would `(char-range \b \n)` etc.

Comment: @OmriBernstein I agree. Actually, I thought the code (map char (range...)), then I changed to use ->> macro for readability. It seems personal taste.

Comment: @Omni What makes this question interesting is that `(char-range \a \z)` stops at `\y`, `(inc \z)` is invalid and if `char-range` were doing `inc` it would be inconsistent with `range`. The only "good" option I could see is another helper function `(defn next-char [ch] (-> ch int inc char))`

Comment: @dimagog Excellent points. I forgot that I would run into a problem without using `inc`. My personal opinion is that it would be cleaner to simply include the `inc` within the `char-range` function definition (which is in fact mikera's answer below), because when getting a char range you would probably almost always want it to be inclusive in that way. It *would* be inconsistent with how `range` works, and that is certainly problematic. Maybe calling it a slightly different name would be a good idea. Maybe `char-range-inclusive` or `char-range+`.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

If code looks "verbose" it's often just a sign that you should factor it out into a separate function. As a bonus you get the chance to give the function a meaningful name.

Just do something like this and your code will be much more readable:

```
(defn char-range [start end]
  (map char (range (int start) (inc (int end)))))

(char-range \a \f)
=> (\a \b \c \d \e \f)
```

Answer (score 17):

According to [this StackOverflow Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10712645/clojure-generate-all-keyboard-typeable-characters) a simple solution would be:

`(map char (range 97 123))`

Comment: Seems simple, however, I wanted to avoid magic number like 97, 123, etc.

Comment: Something simple like `(map char (range (int \a) (int \z)))` avoids magic numbers.

Comment: Just a tiny little correction: `(map char (range (int \a) (inc (int \z))))`

Answer (score 9):

AFAIK, no such a fancy way as Scala. How about

```
(flatten (partition 1 "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"))
```

#### Edit

More fancy way, thanks to @rhu

```
(seq "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz") ; if you copied this from an earlier version, \w and \v were in the wrong positions
```

Comment: Well, if I type the chars "abc...z", I don't need to generate it.

Comment: ;) Although you need type 26 chars, this way is much clear to understand. If you don't like, the `(map char (range ...` is the only way for it, I think. Anyway, Scala does works for you, but clojure doesn't, so..

Comment: Yes, you're right. I agree that your code is clear to understand. Thank you for your answer and comment. What I wanted to know is that the code I wrote is the best way, or there are any other fancy way to do this job.

Comment: @xiaowl: no need to use flatten & partition ... try:  (seq "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz")

Comment: @rhu much simpler than (flatten (partition...)). Thank you.

Comment: @xiaowl (seq "abc...z") seems to be most succinct and clear to understand for me.

Answer (score 3):

If you're interested in a library that gives you a convenient `char-range` function, my library `djy` has one: see [`djy.char/char-range`](https://github.com/daveyarwood/djy/blob/74e1992/src/djy/char.clj#L123-L141).

```
boot.user=> (char-range \a \z)
(\a \b \c \d \e \f \g \h \i \j \k \l \m \n \o \p \q \r \s \t \u \v \w \x \y \z)
```

It even handles supplemental Unicode characters that are large enough that they require 2 characters, representing them as strings:

```
boot.user=> (char-range (char' 0x1f910) (char' 0x1f917))
("" "" "" "" "" "" "" "")
```

[djy: a library of character utility functions for Clojure](https://github.com/daveyarwood/djy)

Answer (score 1):

If you're in clojurescript, you'll need to do something slightly different:

```
(map String/fromCodePoint
  (range (.codePointAt \a 0) 
         (.codePointAt \z 0)))
```

Thank you to the poster for [this answer on clojureverse](https://clojureverse.org/t/how-to-iterate-through-all-alphabet-letters-in-clojurescript/9131/2).