# Clojure can make alphabet list like Haskell?

Tags: haskell, clojure

Haskell can do this:

```
['a'..'z']
```

Have Clojure easy expression like Haskell?

Comment: duplication of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11670941/generate-character-sequence-from-a-to-z-in-clojure

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There isn't a straightforward equivalent to Haskell's syntax, but there are several alternatives, to mention a few:

```
(map char (range (int \a) (inc (int \z))))

(seq "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuwvxyz")
```

Either way, the result will be:

```
(\a \b \c \d \e \f \g \h \i \j \k \l \m \n \o \p \q \r \s \t \u \v \w \x \y \z)
```

Answer (score 4):

If it doesn't exist, you could always write it.

```
(defn letter-range [start end]
  (map char (range (int (.charAt start 0))
                   (inc (int (.charAt end 0))))))

(letter-range "a" "z")
=> (\a \b \c \d \e \f \g \h \i \j \k \l \m \n \o \p \q \r \s \t \u \v \w \x \y \z)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're into arrow ops, you can write...

```
(->> [\a \z]
     (map int)
     (apply #(list %1 (inc %2)))
     (apply range)
     (map char))
```